# Arrange two output pairs into a single matrix on MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm using a command on MATLAB that gives me the output in the following format:

```
ans =

  120.5000  226.5000


ans =

  192.5000  223.0000
```

I get this two outputs pairs at the same time doing:

```
s  = regionprops(binFrameRed, 'centroid', 'area');
s.Centroid;
```

Where s.Centroid are the centroid coordinates of two red squares on an image.

I would like to arrange these outputs into a single matrix, where the first row is given by the first output pair and the second row is given by the second output pair.

I know that I can do this using `reshape`, but for me it would be better if I can use a more direct way.

Does anybody know how can I implement this?

Comment: Which command gives that output? Post the relevant code

Comment: I'm using 's  = regionprops(binFrameRed, 'centroid', 'area');' and if I do 's.centroid' I get the outputs described in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);
```

Example output for some binary image with two centroids:

```
s.Centroid

ans =

  316.0324  202.4018


ans =

  506.7500  135.5469



centroids = cat(1, s.Centroid);    
centroids

centroids =

  316.0324  202.4018
  506.7500  135.5469
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the fun of using square brackets:

```
[s(:,1).Centroid;s(:,2).Centroid]
```